# Hot towel template: how to get the html helper methods to show up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using [John Papa's hot towel template](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/), I have this problem.

In index.cshtml, the htmlhelper functions don't show up. This means no @Html.RenderPartial or Html.Partial, actionlink, etc, nothing.

When trying to get them, I add in the root web.config namespaces pointing to System.Web.Mvc.Html. Like so:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

But this inevitably causes an error like   “Index.cshtml does not inherit from ‘System.Web.WebPages.WebPage’”.
Even when I can add @inherits at the top of my page.

Comment: Compare your Library references (Solution Explorer->ProjectName->References) to those of a new MVC project created from a default MVC template.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's the line that needs to be changed

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

Try inheriting from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage` and see if that does not have any impact on the whole SPA app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried that as well, and still get the same error. This doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: Correction, if replace pageBaseType by System.Web.WebPages.WebPage, I get this error:

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0308: The non-generic type 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage' cannot be used with type arguments

Source Error:


Line 35:     
Line 36:     
Line 37:     public class _Page_index_cshtml : System.Web.WebPages.WebPage<dynamic> {
Line 38:         
Line 39: #line hidden